# How can I make URL action work from a vue component

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vuejs2

I'm working on a small project with ASP.NET MVC and VueJs. I created some components and added them to the Project.js file like so:

```
<div class="card_four">
  <a href="@Url.Action('LoanRequest', 'LoanOrigination')">APPLY NOW 
    <i class="icon">
      <svg width="8" height="13" viewBox="0 0 8 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M0.584961 11.5841L5.17099 6.99807L0.584961 2.41205L1.99896 0.998047L7.99899 6.99807L1.99896 12.9981L0.584961 11.5841Z" fill="white"></path>
      </svg>
    </i>
  </a>
  <p>No collateral Needed</p>
</div>
```

When I clicked on the link, the asp.net MVC URL link broke. How can I rewrite this URL action in the vuejs compatible format as I'm new to VueJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ symbol is razor syntax.  In js frameworks you no longer have the @ symbol.  In the case of urls, you usually just use strings.  Just use

```
<a href='/loanorigination/loanrequest'>APPLY NOW
```

Or for more flexibility, look up Vue Properties and pass it in to your component as a property called something like loanUrl and use {loanUrl} in place of the string above.